# a strange thing by using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I met a strange problem while I'm using pandas with Python.

```
train.head()
Out[201]: 
    user_id  item_id cate_id action_type         action_time
0  11482147   492681    1_11        view 2017-02-15 16:00:00
1  12070750   457406    1_14   deep_view 2017-02-15 16:00:00
2  12431632   527476     1_1        view 2017-02-15 16:00:00
3  13397746   531771     1_6   deep_view 2017-02-15 16:00:00
4  13794253   510089    1_27   deep_view 2017-02-15 16:00:00

train_user = unique(train.iloc[:,0])

train_user
Out[203]: 
array(['0365F7AE-5048-42B3-BB2C-8E637A380A3E',
       '06068254-792D-4AFE-AC6C-DE43DB15D735',
       '077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795', ...,
       'd47465895418527101d0ca0a44586763',
       'ef443bb4e64d4a93a3babb83fb07cf04',
       'f69fb63a3673456c9713bff4af597e95'], dtype=object)
```

Why become the user_id such things?

Comment: what is `unique`. Is it the `pandas` function. Do you have anywhere in your come `from pandas import *`?

Comment: Thanks. I add from pandas import *,then it becomes OK.

Comment: Are you trying to see which are the unique USER_IDs?

Comment: Well in that case, Just for best practice, I suggest that you use `import pandas as pd`, and then use the command `pd.unique(...)`, instead.

Comment: What is it that you find strange here? The fact that it returned an array instead of a Series or a DataFrame?

Comment: @ayhan I'm guessing the OP is looking at the head and expecting the output of `pd.unique` to match the order of the result produced while it's implicity stated there is no ordering and it's a hash based unique (which contains uuid-esque like entries - which could look like something's gone a bit strange). So I'm thinking the answer is "nothing has happened to them - they're just other unique entries somewhere in the dataset not shown in your `.head()`"